# How to add a Variable to post query

Tags: query

the query is :

```
<?php 
// Headlines variable can control admin area
// Its like ; 3,4,5,6
$headlines = ".get_option('t_turmanset').";
query_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'post__in' => array( HOW CAN I ADD HEADLINES ? ) ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

?>
```

Thank you ;)
Ps. sorry about my bad english

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is this that you need, but try to "explode" it...

```
<?php 
    // Headlines variable can control admin area

    // Does this return the string "2,3,4,5" ???
    $headlines = get_option('t_turmanset');

    query_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'post__in' => explode(",", $headlines) ) );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didint work for me.